# Is there way to write this shorter or more efficient?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-on

I have ten blocks of code like this, it is all for dynamically created content:

```
$(document).on('click', '.item' , function() {
    //... do something
});

$(document).on('click', '.element' , function() {
    //... do something different
});
```

Is there a way to write this shorter or more efficient?

Comment: I don't think so... other than may be bind the handler to a more specific element(a static ancestor element which is shared between all the target dynamic elements) other than the document object...

Comment: i think you need to start looking at backbone :) as your question is all about writing code efficient i think once you flew past jquery next step is backbone, backbone will allow you to manage your code in small modules. i believe that's what you are trying to find.

Comment: Why don't you chain your `.on` calls?

Comment: While hardik's statement about "Backbone allowing you to manage your code better" is true, that has nothing to do with your current question. Using a JS framework is probably not going to made your code run faster. It might help you write code in shorter timespan, sometimes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could cache your document selector.

```
var $document = $(document);

$document.on('click', '.item' , function() {
    //... do something
});

$document.on('click', '.element' , function() {
    //... do something different
});
```

But that's about it.

**Edit:** Contribute a test to my [jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/jquery-calling-on-effeciently) if you want hard data.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it's not. That's the only way because content inside the function is different

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could do is create a map between selectors and handlers:

```
var handlers = {
  '.item' : function() {
    //... do something
   },

  '.element' : function() {
    //... do something different
  }
}
```

Then you can assign the handlers in one swift iteration:

```
var $doc = $(document); // no need to wrap the document each time
for (var selector in handlers) {
  if (handlers.hasOwnProperty(selector))
    $doc.on('click', selector, handlers[selector]);      
}
```

One more comment (see @ArunPJohny's comment), regarding efficiency. If you can get away with assigning the handler to an element lower in the DOM tree (farther from document), you should. In this construct:

```
$(static).on('click', dynamic, f);
```

For each click event that reaches an element in the $(static) collection, the dynamic selector is matched to see if f should be triggered. If static is the document, then all clicks in the page will be matched. If you can get a more specific element, less clicks will be matched. For clicks you might not notice a big difference, but events that are triggered faster (mousemove) may give you trouble.

Comment: This is less efficient because you are introducing a loop into the program.

Comment: I sincerily doubt that in code that deals with the DOM the speed bottleneck is a loop over 10 elements instead of repeated code. Feel free to make a jsPerf if you really think this code will run slower on any modern browser.

Comment: One thing which could indeed make it run slower would be a heavy poisoning of Object.prototype. I also doubt that happens in real situations and a solution could be to inherit from null instead of Object.prototype, solution which i didn't choose because it was more verbose.

Comment: I'll take you up on that: http://jsperf.com/jquery-calling-on-effeciently. You're right in that the difference is negligible. When I tested this, at first the "for in" test was actually faster than the one manually calling `.on()`; but then I realized that I was performing function expressions _in_ the loop. So I allowed the "manual" test to also use the preparationally-defined functions that "for in" was using (see 5 & 6), and it appears manually calling `.on()` is an ever-so-slightly faster operation (on my machine).

Comment: Ran it several times and the best solution varied between runs. After 4 runs the filtered for-in and the correct manual chaining both have 9201 ops per second. As i said, a loop doesn't make much difference in this context and improving other aspects (such as not creating a new jQuery object for each call of on) would pay off more.